# Applying function based on a condtion dataframe after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I would like to perform a function on a set of numbers after a groupby, but this function only works when a certain condition is met. Is there a way to perform two different operations?

Say we want to apply the function 1/x after groupby. This of course cannot be done for x==0, but we just want to get 0 as a return value. Normally, this would look something like this

`if x > 0: return 1/x else: return 0`

However, doing

`df.groupby(by = ["index"]).apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 0 else 1/x)`

gives me an error message:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`.

The constructed data is as follows:

after a groupby, I am left with

df =
| index| value1|
| --- | -----|
| a |0 |
| b | 0.5|
| c | 0.2|,
where the indices are no longer callable.

I also have dataset

dg =

| index | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 5 |
| a | 2 | 8 |
| c | 3 | 7 |
| c | 7 | 7 |
| b | 5 | 6 |
| b | 7 | 13 |

I join on the indices using

dh = pd.merge(dg, df, how = 'left', on = index)`.

Now i would like to apply the function

`dh.groupby(by=index).apply(lambda x: (((x.value2/x.value3) - x.value1)**2).sum() / (x.value1 * (x.n.count()))`,

which can obviously not be performed when value1 is equal to zero. Putting the condition in as mentioned before gives me the aforementioned error. What do I do?

Comment: It would be helpful if a sample input/output dataframe was included with your question.

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: The error i got was: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a function that do this for you:-

```
def func(x):
    if x['value1'].gt(0).all():
        return 1/x['value1']
    else:
        return ((((x['value2']/x['value3'])-x['value1'])**2).sum()/x['value1']*x['value1'].count())
```

Now just use:-

```
dh.groupby(by = ["index"]).apply(func)
```

Output:-

```
index   
a      0    inf
       1    inf
b      4    2.0
       5    2.0
c      2    5.0
       3    5.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for a single column. Is there a way to expand this to two columns, where the condition is based on one column?

Comment: Yes what is your condition?

Comment: I say i have columns a and b. I would then like to do something like `.apply(lamda x: 0 if x.b = 0 else x.a.sum()/x.b) `

Comment: can you post output of your df...ie ouput of `print(df)` or how your dataframe look like or post a small part of your dataframe

Comment: I understand. I have adjusted the question description, where i include the complete set up

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, doing this gives me the error that 'bool' object is not callable'``

Comment: I updated my answer according to your condition....kindly have a look

Comment: This works, thanks for your help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.groupby(by = ["index"]).transform(lambda x: [0 if y == 0 else 1/y for y in x.to_list()])
```

This works fine on multiple columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'A':[0,1,2,3,4, 5], 'B':[50, 40,30,20,10, 0]})

print(df)

   index  A   B
0      0  0  50
1      0  1  40
2      0  2  30
3      1  3  20
4      1  4  10
5      1  5   0

df.groupby(by = ["index"]).transform(lambda x: [0 if y == 0 else 1/y for y in x.to_list()])

Output:

          A         B
0  0.000000  0.020000
1  1.000000  0.025000
2  0.500000  0.033333
3  0.333333  0.050000
4  0.250000  0.100000
5  0.200000  0.000000
```

### Explanation

As `groupby.apply()` is passed with a dataframe, the `x` in `lambda x` is actually a fraction of a dataframe based on a group.  Hence, the text `x == 0` is comparing a dataframe with 0 and gives the error.

For `groupby.transform()`, it is passed with a Series instead of dataframe.  Thus, we can use `Series.to_list()` function to get its individual elements and works on them element-wise.

Comment: But if there are several columns for each row that need to be evaluated, x.to_list() would make a nested list. I then can no longer use y.value1 but must resort to y[0] for example?

Comment: @Mick_99  You didn't mention such such cross column operation requirement at the beginning and made a big change to the question after several answers were posted.  Please note to write your requirement as clearly as possible in one go in the future.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I got some feedback so I changed it!